# Byte array to excel workbook

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, excel, byte

I am trying to convert a  byte array to an excel workbook. When I do this with

```
Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);
```

it works fine and the file is as expected. But when I try to do it with this which I found online:

```
private Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
    memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    Object obj = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
    return obj;
}
```

I get an error:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.
```

Is there a difference in how binary write and deserialize work? How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You will get a better response if you tag this with tags for the language you're coding in, and/or [tag:.NET].

Comment: Any updates for this process since 2014?

Answer (score 11):

I am assuming you are trying to do `Object workBook = ByteArrayToObject(renderedBytes);` which turns out not to work as expected.

Since you are stating that `Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);` works as expected (by which you probably mean you can save the response and open it in Excel), the binary data in `renderedBytes` is a valid Excel workbook in the Excel file format.

It appears that you are trying to parse the data in the Excel file format contained in `renderedBytes` using a `BinaryFormatter`. `BinaryFormatter` however, does not know how to parse the Excel file format: it is designed to parse a specific (proprietary?) binary serialization format and *nothing else*. That is, you can only use it to deserialize data that was generated with a call to `BinaryFormatter.Serialize`. An Excel file does not meet this requirement.

In order to actually parse an Excel workbook in binary form to a C# object, you will have to use a library that can do so, such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/):

```
private ExcelPackage ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(arrBytes))
    {
        ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(memStream);
        return package;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any updates on this process since 2014? Are there any simple ways without a 3rd-party?