# Save byte as excel file on the server side

Tags: c#

I have a method that returns a stream which will be written as an excel file on the clientside
Before getting to the client side I will like to write the file to a path and make sure
it is working.

How can I write bytes to a path on the c drive?

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetTaxCodeMap(int fileId)
        {
            var result = await _myFileService.GetMyData(fileId);

            if (result == null)
            {
                return NotFound("File does not exist.");
            }

                       
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                result.CopyTo(memoryStream);
              
                var path = @"Workbk.xlsx";
                var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                
                File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes); //? Not working
                
                //return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", $"Workbk.xlsx");
            }

            return ok
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762274/byte-array-to-excel-workbook

Comment: something, that is very common in memorystreams: reset the position to 0. After `result.CopyTo(memoryStream);` add a ` memoryStream.Position=0; ` before calling `memoryStream.ToArray();`

Comment: what is the return type of GetMyData

Comment: The return type is a stream